# how to upload several images to whatsapp web

Tags: javascript, whatsapp

I want my users to be able to copy several images from my website to whastapp web.

I've seen that whatsapp web allows certain kind of drag and drop integration. If I select several files from my file browser and drag and drop them into whatsapp web, I can send multiple images. It doesn't work using ctrl+c and ctrl+v.

How could I display images in my website so that a user could drag and drop them into whatsapp web?

Is there a way to do this programatically? Like copying base64 encoded images to the clipboard using javascript?